# How to change process title in Swift on Linux?

Tags: swift, vapor, perfect, kitura

Python: `setproctitle`
How to do the same thing in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

You can mutate that `ProcessInfo.processName` property:

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName = "New Name"
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1416428-processname) for this property does give this warning

> User defaults and other aspects of the environment might depend on the process name, so be very careful if you change it. Setting the process name in this manner is not thread safe.

Comment: I tried doing this. It doesn't seem to change the name of a running process in the `ps` output.